# Linker error with MPI_Type_create_resized

Tags: c, mpi, linker-errors

I'm using MPI with C, I've imported `mpi.h` and I am able to use MPI functions like `MPI_Type_create_subarray()` and `MPI_Type_commit()`, but I get a linker error when I try to use `MPI_Type_create_resized()`.

Any idea why I wouldn't have that function, or maybe there is an alternative?

I'm trying to scatter and gather blocks of a 2D array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the documentation for older versions (maybe you had an old implementation that didn't support that function), but even the "ancient" version contains the aforementioned function. This leads me to believe that maybe there was a problem when you downloaded/linked/etc the library. Maybe try re-downloading and setting up the library and see if that fixes it?

Also could you post your errors so we have a better context of the situation.

Comment: I'm actually working on a university server... so that actually makes perfect sense. They probably haven't updated it in years. Unfortunately, I don't have any control over installed packages... and yeah the error was just `undefined reference to 'MPI_Type_create_resized'`

Comment: yeah the mpicc version is 1.2.7 :(

Comment: Yup, that would be the reason then! Maybe you can convince the admin of the server to update.

Comment: You could try to build a copy of MPI just for yourself and install it in your home directory.